How to shift an odd sized image in Fourier space using numpy
I'm developing a function to shift an image in Fourier space. The function needs to work for even and odd sizes.
The code works very well for even sizes, but not for the odd ones. This is what I have so far:
def phase_shift_2d(fourier_image_data: np.ndarray, x0: float, y0: float):
    # Shift image to position x0, y0 in Fourier space.
    image_shape = fourier_image_data.shape

    if image_shape[0] != image_shape[1]:
        u_data = np.arange(0, image_shape[1])
    else:
        u_data = np.arange(-image_shape[1] // 2, image_shape[1] // 2)

    v_data = np.arange(-image_shape[0] // 2, image_shape[0] // 2)

    u, v = np.meshgrid(u_data, v_data)

    ku =  u / image_shape[1]
    kv =  v / image_shape[0]

    shifted_fimage = fourier_image_data * np.exp(-2. * 1j * np.pi * (ku * x0 + kv * y0))

    return shifted_fimage

import numpy as np
N=256

image = np.zeros((N,N), dtype=float)
image[N//2,N//2] = 1.0
image[N//2+35,N//2+35] = 0.5


fourier_image = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.rfft2(np.fft.ifftshift(image, axes=(-2,-1))), axes=-2)

x0_shift = np.random.randint(low=-N//2, high=N//2, size=1, dtype=int)
y0_shift = np.random.randint(low=-N//2, high=N//2, size=1, dtype=int)

shifted_fourier_image = phase_shift_2d(fourier_image, x0_shift[0], y0_shift[0])

shifted_image = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.irfft2(np.fft.ifftshift(shifted_fourier_image, axes=-2)), axes=(-2,-1))

final_y, final_x = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(shifted_image.real), shifted_image.real.shape)[0], np.unravel_index(np.argmax(shifted_image.real), shifted_image.real.shape)[1]

assert final_x == x0_shift + N//2
assert final_y == y0_shift + N//2


You will get:
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[78], line 1
----> 1 assert final_x == x0_shift + N//2
      2 assert final_y == y0_shift + N//2

AssertionError: 

The position of the point source in the y-axis seems to be ok, but it's not the case for the position in the x-axis. I guess this is related with the different size of the Fourier image when doing the rfft2, where the shape of the array is (N, N/2+1). However, I don't know how to fix this.

Maybe a question that should be asked at DSP StackExchange. But I can recommend dumbing down your example to 1D to see the best way to specify the shift. I assume there are some problems with the identification of the DC component. Check the implementation of fftshift also, they have some nice comments that might benefit you

I have solved this by using rfftfreq and fftfreq numpy functions. The phase_shift function now looks like this:
def phase_shift_grid_2d(fourier_image_data: da.Array, x0: float, y0: float):
    # Shift image to position x0, y0 in Fourier space.
    image_shape = fourier_image_data.shape

    if image_shape[0] != image_shape[1]:
        u_data = da.fft.rfftfreq(image_shape[0])
    else:
        u_data = da.fft.fftfreq(image_shape[1])

    v_data = da.fft.fftfreq(image_shape[0])

    ku, kv = da.meshgrid(u_data, v_data)

    shifted_fimage = fourier_image_data * da.exp(-2. * 1j * np.pi * (ku * x0 + kv * y0))

    return shifted_fimage

